# How to highlight CSS grid cells?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Consider a CSS grid where rows can have variable heights:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
  grid-row-gap: 8px;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.second {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
</div>
```

When hovering on the grid element in DevTools, Chrome visualizes the grid like this:

[image]

How could I achieve a similar grid overlay effect using CSS (or JavaScript, if needed)?

**Notes:**

1. All grid cells should be highlighted, even if grid items don't occupy them.
2. Grid cells can have variable heights (in the example above the first row height is smaller than the rest of the rows).

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/building-css-grid-overlay/

Comment: @Michael_B That solution doesn't seem to support variable row heights.

Comment: Right. It's not an easy request because the Dev Tool grid overlay highlights the *structure* of the grid. CSS doesn't deal in the abstract; it styles actual elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One idea using JS is to read the computed value of `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` in order to create another grid above the one you have filled with placeholder elements.

Here is a basic example. You should update the values on hover since `getComputedStyle` will return pixel values:

```js
var grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
var overlay = document.createElement("div");
overlay.className = 'overlay';
overlay.style.gridTemplateRows = window.getComputedStyle(grid, null).getPropertyValue("grid-template-rows");
overlay.style.gridTemplateColumns = window.getComputedStyle(grid, null).getPropertyValue("grid-template-columns");
grid.appendChild(overlay);

/* Get the number of items*/
var Nc = overlay.style.gridTemplateColumns.split(" ").length;
var Nr = overlay.style.gridTemplateRows.split(" ").length;
/* Create placeholder items*/
for (var i = 0; i < Nc * Nr; i++) {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  overlay.appendChild(d);
}

/* Update the values on hover*/
grid.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  overlay.style.gridTemplateRows = window.getComputedStyle(grid, null).getPropertyValue("grid-template-rows");
  overlay.style.gridTemplateColumns = window.getComputedStyle(grid, null).getPropertyValue("grid-template-columns");
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
  grid-row-gap: 8px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.second {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 120px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  grid-gap: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.overlay>* {
  border: 1px dotted;
  background: rgba(0, 125, 0, 0.4);
}

.grid:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you explain what you mean by "You should update the values on hover since getComputedStyle will return pixel values"?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko getComputedStyle will return the actual value based on screen size .. for example if you define a template using `1fr` you will not get `1fr` but the pixel value of `1fr` considering your actual screen size so if you change the size of the screen you need to get the new value again .. You can inspect the element to see that the templates are defined using pixel values. I said you need to change this on hover but you can also do it on screen resize but it's better on hover so you do the cacluation only when needed.

Comment: Assuming that the number of rows and columns won't change, we could give overlay grid items a `grid-row` and a `grid-column` instead of setting `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns` on the grid. That way you don't need to recalculate on window resize, right?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko no, setting grid-row/column is not needed if you have the correct number of items because they will placed automatically to fill all the grid cells. You will always need to get the value of grid-template-* but in case you know the template you can use inherit . Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltavbncr/2/ .. here I consider the fact that you defined the template columns to have 8 element so I can inherit this and I don't need to calculate it but I need to do it for the row because it's dymanic and based on your elements

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! Minor question: what's the importance of `overflow: hidden` on the grid?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko since I update the values only on hover sometimes the overlay grid will get bigger but is invisble. adding overflow:hidden will avoid having the scroll bar ... you can keep the overlay with opacity:1 to notice this

Answer (score 1):

Create elements for each grid cell:

```
const grid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid")[0];

const rows = 4;
const cols = 8;

for (let r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
    for (let c = 1; c <= cols; c++) {
        const h = document.createElement("div");
        h.classList.add("highlight");
        h.style.gridRow = r;
        h.style.gridColumn = c;
        grid.appendChild(h);
    }
}
```

(This could also be done server side)

And style them:

```
.highlight {
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  background: #0000FF44;
}
```

To show them only on hover use:

```
.highlight {
    display: none;
}

.grid:hover > .highlight {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: How would this approach work with existing grid items?

Comment: It ignores them. Grid display allows multiple elements in a single "cell" without interfering each other. They are draw on top of each other. That's what the `z-index` is for: to determine the drawing order.