# Is it possible to draw all CSS grid lines as dotted borders or outlines (if JS is allowed)?

Tags: css, css-grid

For the following CSS grid:

```css
#my-css-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 20px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 20px);
  background: #ffc;
  outline: 1px dotted orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-css-grid">
</div>
```

Can we draw the grid line borders or outlines like below:

[image]

Google Chrome actually draws them in the debug inspect mode, while Firefox and Safari do not. Can the grid lines be drawn (1) if we cannot use JavaScript, or (2) if JavaScript can be used?

Comment: question modified to allow using JS

Comment: How would allowing JavaScript change the answer? The answers in the proposed duplicate still apply. Whether you add the extra elements manually or through script is immaterial.

Comment: @HereticMonkey if JS is allowed, then can't you just add all the grid cells and add the CSS style?

Comment: You can emulate this by setting the background of the grid parent to black, then give a grid-gap of whatever thickness you want the borders to be. https://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/e6Lnc5m8/2/

Comment: @TylerH is it true that you have to have all the grid cells?

Comment: @nopole I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: "Whether you add the extra elements manually or through script is immaterial." Unless you're asking how to add the elements, which is a duplicate of several other questions...

Comment: Also FYI there is a feature-request for this exact functionality to be added to the spec. https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2748

Answer (score -2):

If you want sure.

For the container div you would have

```
border-top-style: dotted;
border-bottom-style: dotted;
```

And then for each inner cell in your grid (except the first cell of each row) you'd just write:

```
border-right-style: dotted;
```

You really wouldn't need javascript if you're dynamically building the grid.

I feel like I'm missing the question here

Comment: then you probably have to use DOM scripting to add all the cells

Comment: Absolutely, if you want an easy life

Comment: being ironic? actually DOM scripting is not as difficult as before

Comment: No I was serious. Why wouldn't you do DOM scripting for something like this?

Comment: I think my answer was sufficient. Would like a good reason as to why I got a down vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote you by the way... maybe somebody thought your answer wasn't a complete solution

Comment: oh somebody actually did it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205867/how-to-highlight-css-grid-cells